# Generic Message - "To use this feature, use the Messenger app"

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have a generic template message with a element_share button. When using a desktop browser, the share button is greyed out and on hover the following comes up: 
`To use this feature, use the Messenger app`

I checked the docs and couldn't find anything regarding this. Is there a limitation to the share button on desktop?

Comment: Yes, right now that isn't supported on the web client. You can share from the webview on web though: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/sharing/v2.10